# Deleting Multiple Items DynammoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DB table in `AWS DynamoDB`

```
+------------+----------+-------------+---------------+
| email (PK) | uid (SK) | isConnected | connectionExp |
+------------+----------+-------------+---------------+
```

`email` attribute could be duplicated.

I am trying to delete items follow `connectionExp`.

```
export const delete = (e, ctx, cb) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: "MyTable",
    /*
      I want to skip Key attribute if I can.
    */
    ConditionExpression: "isConnected == :isConnected and connectionExp <= :connectionExp",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":isConnected": false,
      ":connectionExp": moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    }
  }
  DYNAMO_DB.delete(params, (err, data) => { ... });
}
```

The above code doesn't work.

How can I delete my items with efficiency

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: @Dunedan Unfortunately, I don't know how to see the Error msg in `AWS Lambda`. I just get `"Internal server error"`

Comment: I guess it' caused by skipping `Key` attrbute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your logs, either run your lambda locally and check debug console, or if running within AWS check your **cloudwatch logs**. That will give you the exact error, however, you're correct in your comment that the key is a required field so your code won't work in its current state.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html

Can you set the **TTL (time to live)** attribute on your table to be your *connectionExp* field. Dynamo will automatically delete any records surpassing your *connectionExp* field. This however won't take into account your **isConnected** field.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

You can also perform a **scan** on the table to find the records to delete (this is slow if your table grows).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html